# Slightly confused with coordinates

Tags: objective-c

Hi I have such code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];         

    // Get view bounds
    CGRect bounds = [self.view bounds];

    // Get center point
    CGPoint center;
    center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width/2.0;
    center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height/2.0;


    NSLog(@"center y = %f", center.y);



}
```

The above log initially prints `274.0`

Then I have this method:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)x
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

    CGRect bounds = [[self view] bounds];

    // Get center point
    CGPoint center;
    center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width/2.0;
    center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height/2.0;


    // If the orientation is rotating to Portrait mode...
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(x))
    {
         NSLog(@"In rotation, center y = %f", center.y);      

    }


}
```

This `center.y` in above method is calculated in the same way as the one in viewDidLoad as you might notice. However, when phone is rotated first to landscape then back to portrait as initially, now the `center.y` in the above method always prints 230 (instead of 274.0 as initially) -- why?
What can be causing this?

Comment: Any reason to not use `self.view.center` or at least `CGRectGetMidY(bounds)`?

Comment: Also, are you thinking of the `bounds` or the `frame`?

Comment: Hi David, I am not sure what you mean, just my question is, since center.y is calculated in a similar way both in viewDidLoad and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` -- why are they different in these methods? (after rotations happens first to landscape and then back to portrait) ??

Comment: Autoresizing? *will* rotate vs *did* rotate?

Comment: @David Rönnqvist: I am not sure fully what you mean and how is that related with calculating `center.y` as I mentioned in my post

Comment: http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html

Comment: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation means it will rotate i.e
it is not rotated at the time you tried to execute that code.

Comment: @David Rönnqvist: David none of your posts directly answer my question!

Comment: Ok, lets think of it like this. The calculation is the same in both cases which mean that either the origin or the size must have changed. The origin almost never changes so it's more likely that the size has changed. (This can *easily* be verified by logging the bounds before the calculation.) One thing that is likely to change the size is autoresizing (which I linked to an explanation of).

Comment: @David Rönnqvist: David, I find it strange. Initially, the self.view.bounds.size.height is 548. Then imagine I rotate to Landscape mode. And then again back to portrait mode. Now, the self.view.bounds.size.height is 460 -- and it stays like this all the time. Don't you find it strange?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    CGRect bounds = [[self view] bounds];
    CGPoint center;
    center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width/2.0;
    center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height/2.0;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(fromInterfaceOrientation)){
        NSLog(@"In rotation, center y = %f", center.y);
    }
}
```